# Is there a way to redirect hosts with Frida without the Interceptor API?

Tags: javascript, python, frida

I'm trying to redirect a clients server from one to another, but because I need to use

```
"code_signing": "required"
```

I can't use the Interceptor API.
Does anybody have any scripts that could achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should give more details on what you are trying to to. For example you forget to mention which platform you are using Frida with. because of `code_signing` I assume you are trying to use Frida on an iOS app, correct? Please edit your question and describe in detail what you are trying to do, how far you got and what your problem is.